# Is there a specific reason that the universe is precluded from expanding into anything? Or is it simply not required in the mathematics?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, spacetime-dimensions, cosmological-inflation

We know that the universe doesn't need to expand into anything to support current theories, but is there a reason that it is specifically precluded from doing so? In other words, is there any evidence to specifically indicate that the universe doesn't expand into or against any medium, or is it simply the case that it is not required to do so to support current physics, and therefore not considered? My question essentially is regarding the difference between the **absence** of evidence for a specific condition vs. specific evidence **against** that same condition.

Comment: What do you mean by "the universe"?

Comment: it is not required to be a higher dimensional space into which to expand, but it is not precluded either.

Comment: The universe is everything. How can it, that is everything, expand into something, when that something must already be part of everything. It looks like you're confised by our ordinary intuitive understanding of 'expands'.

Comment: @Jack -Although this question's been closed, I think the OP might be interested in the cosmological model of Nikodem Poplawski, described in the numerous preprints he's posted between 2010 and 2021, which can be found by his name on Cornell University's Arxiv site:  The expansion subdivides, into sequentially smaller scales of spacetime, some (and, perhaps, eventually all) of the space vacated by material formed by previous "local universes".   (Like most inflationary cosmological models, Poplawski's describes a multiverse, but his lacks the need for a hypothetical "inflaton" particle.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a finite spherical region of a closed, dust-dominated FLRW universe and embed it in a Schwarzschild background. The combination describes a sphere of matter that expands from an initial singularity (the white-hole singularity of the full Schwarzschild geometry) and recollapses to a final singularity (the black-hole singularity), and is surrounded by an infinite vacuum. If you lived inside the sphere, and far enough from the edge, you probably wouldn't be able to tell that the FLRW region wasn't the whole universe.

There's no apparent reason why the universe would be like that, but it isn't ruled out by the mathematics.

The region of matter being exactly spherical and exactly homogeneous isn't essential to this construction. It just makes it tractable to find an exact solution.

A region of a ΛCDM universe like ours can probably be embedded in a Schwarzschild-de Sitter background as well, but I'm not certain.

This is different from the earlier answers, which talk about extra dimensions. In these solutions, the matter and vacuum are at different locations in the same 3D space, which I think was the intent of the question.

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a downvote but to me this is a nice answer, +1.

Comment: I'd agree, and didn't have the points to blow on any downvoting (which I'd imagine tends to come from very high-reputation participants), except for the Schwarzschild BH, which is non-rotating. Poplawski's model, which I'd touted in my comment on the closed question, depends on universal rotation (for which there's been some observational support), but requires a 1929 version of Einstein's relativity, which differs from 1915's GR and may consequently lack academic support, what with GR being as tough as it is.

Answer (score 3):

We normally say, a balloon expands. If we were being more expansive, we would say it expands into the air.

Note that the air is larger than the balloon. And that both are a small part of eveythimg, but with, of course, the latter small thing larger than the preceding small thing.

Thus a thing expands when the thing, a small part of everything, expands into a larger part of everything.

But how can we describe expansion when the thing that is expanding is everything? There is no more room for it to expand into - everything is taken up by the thing itself!

The simple solution is to find an alternative way to describe expansion. We do this by marking two points on the thing at a certain time and measuring the distance between them. A year later, we again measure that distance. If this distance is smaller, then we say it contracts; if equal, we say it is static; and of it is greater, we say it has expanded. The primary motivation for this definition is that it does not refer to the totality of things - the All of Aristotle - or in modern language, the universe.

You can see that this definition works equally well for an expanding balloon or an expanding universe whereas the intuitive definition does not.

Answer (score 2):

I think the main reason not to consider an embedding space is [Occam's razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor). The data are perfectly well fit with a 4-dimensional manifold, which does not require an embedding space.

If you were to introduce the embedding space, you would then need some theory which explained how the embedding came about, and what the dynamics are of the extra dimensions. Or, if they are somehow just a flat space, you'd need to explain why those extra dimensions don't obey GR. That's a lot of complication to add, without explaining anything about physics.

People do consider extra dimensional models in cosmology all the time, so-called [braneworld scenarios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology). However, the brane is not "expanding into" these extra dimensions, in the sense that the brane is not a finite volume submanifold whose volume is growing in the full space.

Comment: I think the 4th dimension to which you're referring is time, but could you verify that?  (I'm unusually dependent on verbiage, for my limited understanding of physics.)

Comment: Yes, that is correct.